# French nationality for grand son of French nationals, when the parent didn't claim the nationality

Tags: france, french-citizens, nationality

My great grand parent were both French nationals, my grand mother was born outside of France, but never claims her French nationality due to the lack of a near French embassy, she die some years ago. Is his son, my father, eligible for the French nationality? If its yes, I'm eligible after he gets

Comment: The purported duplicate is quite different: grand-father who wasn't born French, grandson trying to establish his citizenship without the father doing it first. My answer to the other question doesn't contain the relevant information, it cannot possibly be considered a duplicate. There are other related questions on this site so it might be possible to find a better one or to piece together an answer based on them but for now I nominated this question to be reopened.